# How to set permission when uploading file to amazon s3 in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

In android when i upload a file to aws s3. It was uploaded successfully. But the uploaded file have no public permission. It cannot access by public.

TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload("appname","filename",file);

But when i rewrite the code as

TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload("acs-android","filename",file,CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

for accessing public permission it shows an error.

Error : Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0xb8f43420: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer.

The full code is

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;   
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferListener;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferState;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GroupGrantee;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Permission;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Region;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;

File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"filename");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fileUpload();
        }
    });
}

private void fileUpload() {

// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "xxx:7e4xxx-xxxxxxxxx-xx-48cfc8f79f6", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.REGION // Region
    );

    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    s3.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.REGION));

    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, this);



    TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload("appname","filename",file,CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);


    transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if(state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {

            Log.e("LOGTAG", "Error : " + ex.getMessage());

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Is this still happening?

Are you sure the only thing that changed was adding the public read permission.

Answer (score 1):

I just use this

```
TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload("acs-android","filename",file,CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
```

and it works fine. 
Make sure you dont have any bucket policy set on the amazon s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PutObjectRequest` in `upload()`

```
getTransferManager().upload(
    new PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, File file)
   .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
);
```

Comment: I have the code like this. But it shows error.   PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest( new PutObjectRequest("acs-android", fileTempName, file) .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead) );
        TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(putObjectRequest);